# How to set a String value from file to a custom class variable?

Tags: java, string, instantiation

I'm trying to instantiate a String object that I read from a file and then set the value of that object as an object of a custom class (Room). Any advice on how I can do that?

This is what I have so far:

```
String roomName = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
//scanning the name of the room from file
  if(room == "room"){
     Room roomName = new Room(roomName);
   }
```

So basically, I'm trying to set the roomName string that I read from the file, and then set that same value as the name of the Room object.

EDIT: the file that I'm trying to read will have either a "door" value or a "room" value, which is why I check if the value is a "room" or not.

The Room class is instantiated like so:

```
Room room0 = new Room(0);
```

The sample file I read is something like this:

```
room 0 wall wall wall
door d0 0 1 close
```

Comment: What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: What is your if-statement trying to check?  (apart from the fact that that is not how you compare strings in java)

Comment: Sorry but what is the problem you are facing? What are you trying to achieve? To be honest your question reminds [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: this is not a duplicate of that question. he doesn't have a infinite set of parameters, he has `(if input.contains("room")) myRoom = new Room(roomName)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your logic:

```
String roomName = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
Room room = null;

if(roomName.equals("room")) {
   room = new Room(roomName);
}
```

By my logic (nothing to check):

```
Room room = new Room(scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : ");
```

**EDIT:**

```
List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
...
if (roomName.equals("room")) {
    rooms.add(new Room(rooms.size())); // rooms.get(0) = room with number 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Java. You can't use variable value (value of roomName) as another variable name.

Comment: "not possible" may be too strong words. Depending on what OP is trying to achieve `Map<String, Foo>` may be quite nice solution.